# Strange result to packaging qt application(ubuntu)

Tags: qt, ubuntu, packaging

I want to packaging qt5 application on ubuntu.

I'm refer to http://blog.naver.com/PostView.nhn?blogId=hseok74&logNo=120193947673

It looks like smoothly.

But It's happen problem at Step 8

```
kkangji@kkangji-HP-Z820-Workstation:~/바탕화면$ dpkg --contents minicam_1.0-1_amd64.deb 

drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2013-08-16 13:35 ./
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2013-08-16 13:35 ./usr/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2013-08-16 13:35 ./usr/bin/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2013-08-16 13:35 ./usr/share/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2013-08-16 13:35 ./usr/share/doc/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2013-08-16 13:35 ./usr/share/doc/minicam/
-rw-r--r-- root/root       174 2013-08-16 13:31 ./usr/share/doc/minicam/changelog.Debian.gz
-rw-r--r-- root/root       251 2013-08-14 16:22 ./usr/share/doc/minicam/README.txt
-rw-r--r-- root/root       173 2013-08-16 13:31 ./usr/share/doc/minicam/README.Debian
-rw-r--r-- root/root      1483 2013-08-16 13:31 ./usr/share/doc/minicam/copyright
lrwxrwxrwx root/root         0 2013-08-16 13:35 ./usr/bin/app_name -> 
../share/minicam/bin/app_name
```

libraries and .run file are missing on package.

What should I do?

-----------rules-------------

```
#!/usr/bin/make -f
# Sample debian/rules that uses debhelper.
# This file is public domain software, originally written by Joey Hess. 
#
# This version is for packages that are architecture dependent.

# Uncomment this to turn on verbose mode.
#export DH_VERBOSE=1

build: build-stamp
build-stamp:
        dh_testdir

 # Add here commands to compile the package.
 #qmake-qt4 -config release
        /home/kkangji/Qt5.1.0/5.1.0/gcc_64/bin/qmake -config release
        make

        touch build-stamp
clean:
        dh_testdir
        dh_testroot
        rm -f build-stamp

        # Add here commands to clean up after the build process.
        #$(MAKE) clean
        #$(MAKE) distclean
        dh_clean

install: build
        dh_testdir
        dh_testroot
        dh_prep
        dh_installdirs

 # Add here commands to install the package into debian/<packagename>
        make INSTALL_ROOT=`pwd`/debian/project install
        mkdir -p `pwd`/debian/project/usr/bin/
        ln -sf /usr/share/project/bin/app_name `pwd`/debian/project/usr/bin/app_name

# Build architecture-independent files here.
binary-indep: build install
# We have nothing to do by default. 
# Build architecture-dependent files here.
binary-arch: build install
        dh_testdir
        dh_testroot
        dh_installchangelogs
        dh_installdocs
        dh_installexamples
        dh_installman
        dh_link
        dh_strip
        dh_compress
        dh_fixperms
        dh_installdeb
        #dh_shlibdeps
        dh_gencontrol
        dh_md5sums
        dh_builddeb

binary: binary-indep binary-arch
```

### .PHONY: build clean binary-indep binary-arch binary install

------------------control-------------------

```
Source: minicam
Section: unknown
Priority: extra
Maintainer: KKANGJI <jhkang@xycron.net>
Build-Depends: debhelper (>= 8.0.0)
Standards-Version: 3.9.2
Homepage: <insert the upstream URL, if relevant>
#Vcs-Git: git://git.debian.org/collab-maint/minicam.git
#Vcs-Browser: http://git.debian.org/?p=collab-maint/minicam.git;a=summary

Package: minicam
Architecture: any
Depends: ${shlibs:Depends}, ${misc:Depends}
Description: <insert up to 60 chars description>
```

Comment: isn't it already packaged for you?

Comment: No, It is empty package.

Comment: Isn't this a packaging question instead of programming? IOW, isn't this off-topic for SO?

Comment: Can you show the control rules and so forth debian files?

Comment: Sure. Thx for take care my problem.

Comment: Why don't you just package it like I documented in here? http://community.kde.org/KDE_Mobile/Harmattan#Packaging_your_KDE_Mobile_application_with_shared_libraries The rules could be a lot simpler. I am not sure why you need all this boilerplate. You will not even need the RPATH in there I set.